# plugins to add compileJava task in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am new to Java and it's build tools. In `build.gradle` file I do not see java or javalibrary id under plugins, which makes me think, which of the following plugin causes the creation of CompileJava task(or calls Java plugin), the list of plugins I see in `build.gradle` is as follows

```
plugins {
    id "jacoco"

    id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.22.RELEASE"

    id "com.abc.tools.aws.build.docker" version "2.0.2"
    id "com.abc.tools.aws.build.abb-bom-management" version "2.0.2"
    id "com.abc.tools.aws.build.microservice" version "2.0.2"    
}
```

Based on the readings, I did not think that `jacoco's` one of the task is to compile java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins in Gradle can apply<sup>1</sup> other plugins to a project because a gradle [project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) is also a [`PluginAware`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginAware.html) object.

My guess is that `org.springframework.boot` is the one that applied the `java` plugin.

*Indeed, I just checked it and [they do](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/73652d8a0795b94fdb97034840e9a673f4306b96/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/SpringBootPlugin.java#L45) apply the plugin*.

**Note that later versions of the plugin [do not do this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/98e21c30025023bedc496f9e7a76aeea7da88aca/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/SpringBootPlugin.java).** If you are bothered about it, it is probably best to update the version you use, however later versions will require later versions of gradle, so upgrade judiciously.

<sub>1. IMO, they shouldn't be doing this and should rely on using [`PluginManager.withPlugin`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager.html#withPlugin-java.lang.String-org.gradle.api.Action-) method</sub>.

Answer (score 1):

The Java plugin adds Java compilation along with testing and bundling capabilities to a project, as well as `compileJava`, `test`, `jar` etc. tasks. More on this [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
```

Jacoco is the plugin which is used for [test coverage reporting](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html).

There is no clear way to get full list of tasks from each plugin, however you can print tasks difference after each plugin has been applied to see how your plugin list is changed i.e.

`build.gradle`

```
def tasksBefore = [], tasksAfter = []    
project.tasks.each { tasksBefore.add(it.name) } // get all tasks

apply(plugin: 'jacoco') // apply plugin

project.tasks.each { tasksAfter.add(it.name) } // get all tasks
tasksAfter.removeAll(tasksBefore); // get the difference

println 'jacoco tasks: ' + tasksAfter;
```

Comment: Thank you, my question was I do not see a Java plugin yet it builds fine, which of the above listed plugin under the hood calls Java plugin?

Comment: I am not sure though where this task is coming from without deeper look into your gradle config, see my updated answer, I've added example how you could see how plugin list is changed after each plugin has been applied